# Validate `~/.vimrc`

Tags: vim, vimrc

I want to validate that my `~/.vimrc` file is correct, basically just by launching `vim` and immediately running `quit`. I can almost do this with `vim -c quit`, except that I have to press the enter key. For example,

```
> cat ~/.vimrc
echoerr 'test'

> vim -c quit
Error detected while processing /home/josh/.vimrc:
line    1:
test
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Is there a way to do this without pressing enter? I guess I could just run `echo | vim -c quit`, but I was hoping there was a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a try-catch block to catch errors (which get converted to exceptions), and fail on any exception:

```
$ cat vimrc-fail                                                
echoerr 'test'                                 
$ cat vimrc-pass
echo 'test'
$ vim -u NONE -c 'try | source vimrc-pass | catch | cq | endtry | q'; echo $?  
0
$ vim -u NONE -c 'try | source vimrc-fail | catch | cq | endtry | q'; echo $?
1
```

From the [help](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#%3Atry):

```
:try                            :try :endt :endtry E600 E601 E602
:endt[ry]               Change the error handling for the commands between
                        ":try" and ":endtry" including everything being
                        executed across ":source" commands, function calls,
                        or autocommand invocations.
```

And from [`:echoerr`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#%3Aechoerr):

> When used inside a try conditional, the message is raised as an error exception instead (see [try-echoerr](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#try-echoerr)).

Other notes:

- `-u NONE` prevents sourcing the default vimrcs
- [`:cq`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3Acq) makes Vim return a non-zero exit status

---

To get the last error message (now actually an exception), use [`v:exception`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#v%3Aexception):

```
$ vim -u NONE -c 'try | source vimrc-fail | catch | silent exec "!echo " shellescape(v:exception) |cq | endtry | q'; echo $?
Vim(echoerr):test
1
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to echo the error message as well?

Comment: @JoshuaSpence I think the last exception is stored in [`v:exception`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#v%3Aexception). Maybe something like `exec "!echo " shellescape(v:exception) | cq` instead of the plain `cq` would work.

Comment: That almost works... it requires me to press enter though.

Comment: Ok, it works if I run `vim` with `-E` and `-s`

Comment: `silent exec` should fix the Enter problem.